# Replacing double quote with a single quote

Tags: c#, replace

I have the following string in c#:

```
string ptFirstName = tboxFirstName.Text;
```

`ptFirstName` returns: `"John"`

I wish to convert this to `'John'`

I have tried numerous variations of the following, but I am never able to replace double quotes with single quotes:

```
ptFirstName.Replace("\"", "'");
```

Can anybody enlighten me?

My goal is to write this to an XML file:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("first",ptFirstName);   // where ptFirstName is 'John' in single quotes.
```

Comment: 1. `Replace` returns a *new* string 2. Why muck with data doing into `WriteAttributeString`? (It should be encoded "correctly" in either case.)

Comment: This is because I need it in that format in an SD card that is read by a device that reads it looking for single quotes - that's the way it is...

Answer (score 19):

The reason

```
ptFirstName.Replace("\"", "'");
```

does not work is that `string` is immutable. You need to use

```
ptFirstName = ptFirstName.Replace("\"", "'");
```

instead. Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/LbGQWe).

Answer (score 2):

I will guess that you didn't type `"John"` into the textbox, but just `John` and you are seeing quotes around the string when you set a breakpoint and are looking at the variable in visual studio?

If so, then realize that the quotes there are not part of the string, but just indicating to you that the value is a string.  They are added by the debugger.  If you were to do:

```
Console.WriteLine(ptFirstName);
```

you would not see the quotes.

Comment: So I guess I have been properly converting it all along. And yet when I write to my xml file, and I WISH to have the xml file display 'John' instead of "John" as in the following example, I trip up...             <patient first='John' last='Doe'>  So perhaps my question should be, how does one write to my xml file using   writer.WriteAttributeString("first",ptFirstName);  and not ending up with double quotes? (I need this because the SD card that I am writing this into is then read by another device which needs the single quote format..)

Answer (score 0):

writer.QuoteChar = '\'';

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.quotechar.aspx for details.