# c# replace double concatenation character with single concatenation in replace method

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

i want to replace double  concatenation  to single concatenation  in c#

I've tried

```
sConfigration.Replace('"',''')
```

plus several other ways.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the value you are having in `sConfigration`

Comment: what's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `Replace` to the original variable:

```
sConfigration = sConfigration.Replace("\"","'");
```

Comment: @upvoters, Why you peoples misusing your privilege for voting snippets that won't compile? the code `.Replace('"',''');` is not syntactically correct

Comment: @un-lucky Why don't you use your privilege to comment in a helpful way and point out possible errors?

Comment: ' ' '  give me syntax error

Comment: Thank u yes is worked

Comment: Well now it's a perfect dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456645/replacing-double-quote-with-a-single-quote)

Comment: @RazLuvaton First of all, I'answered like 5 minutes before you. Second: Escaping a string is nothing anybody needs to copy from you. Thats pathetic!

Comment: @un-lucky What exactly do you want from me?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé: Nothing in particular and personal, I just tried to remind you the site policies

Answer (score 0):

`string` is immutable. `sConfigration.Replace('"',''')` returns *a new string* with the required replacements. If you don't assign it to anything, its as if it hadn't even called the method.

Do the following:

```
 sConfigration = sConfigration.Replace('"',''');
```

And *please* fix the spelling.